# Excel VBA to loop through a table to define a macro variable

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Long story short. I don't have SAS graph and need to produce charts in excel at the State level. So 52 charts (includes District of Columbia and Puerto Rico).

All of the data needed for the charts are in .csv files named like this lr_hpi_&state..csv

What I need to do is iteratively open each .csv file, copy the data and paste it into the chart template.

I created a sheet called states in the chart template workbook that looks like this.

```
    id  state
    1   AK
    2   AL
    3   AR
    4   AZ
    5   CA
```

How would I go about looping through the states sheet to grab the state string one at a time to define a macro variable? I'm thinking I could use the loop counter to define a variable named i and then concatenate i to column "B "& i &" " of the states sheet.

Just can't figure out the syntax.

Thanks.

VBA code I have from a slightly modified recored macro. VBA is not my native language.

Sub stateloop()

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim state As String
state = "AK"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "\\sac-psas-02\pm\ma\scott\OW\hpi trend pci outlier removal\lr_hpi_" & state & ".csv"
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("lr_hpi_template.xlsm").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Windows("lr_hpi_" & state & ".csv").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
ActiveWindow.Close

ChDir "\\sac-psas-02\pm\ma\scott\OW\hpi trend pci outlier removal"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "\\sac-psas-02\pm\ma\scott\OW\hpi trend pci outlier removal\lr_hpi_" & state & ".xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close


Application.Quit
ActiveWorkbooks.Close False
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
Sub stateloop()

Dim i As Long
Dim state As String
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("state")

For i = 2 To 53 ' assuming the first state is on row 2 and so on

    state = sh.Range("B" & i) ' assuming the states are in column B

    ' Rest of code goes here

Next i

End Sub
```